# Is it possible to receive MQTT messages from many IoT devices using only one Lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda, mqtt, aws-iot

We are setting up the infrastructure in AWS to collect data from IOT devices. Once the devices are registered, they will starting sending json messages to a few MQTT topics. In order to receive the messages and parse them and save the data into a database I plan to create a rule which triggers a Lambda function when a message is received. The Lambda function does the parsing.

Based on the [AWS IoT documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-lambda-rule.html), a rule can be created under IoT to evaluate messages sent by your things with query like `SELECT * FROM 'mymsgs/+'`. It appears that the rule is not associated with any particular devices. So can I assume it can listen to the topics from all devices under the same account? If that is the case, I can just have one Lambda function to process all the messages that come from different devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct topic rules are not associated with any device. Use the FROM statement to control what messages they receive. You might want to update the SQL statement to

```
SELECT * as data, topic() as topic FROM mymsgs/+
```

so that your lambda can know which topic the message was sent on. If a device publishes `{ foo: "bar", baz: 100 }` on topic `mymsgs/device` then

```
{
  "data": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": 0
  },
  "topic": "mymsgs/device1"
}
```

will be send to the lambda function.

You can also use IoT policies attached to thing certificates to enforce that a thing is only publishing on the topics it should.

Comment: Your SELECT statement basically covers all topics, right? And `data` in your SELECT statement will be used as input of the lambda function?

Comment: I've updated the example. The SELECT clause controls what is send to lambda (or other rule actions), the FROM clause controls which topics using MQTT topic wildcards + and #. The WHERE clause can filter based on data in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of topics is less you can do the following

```
SELECT *, topic() as topic FROM 'mylog/+' where regexp_matches(topic(), 'mylog/\b(info|error|warn)\b') = TRUE
```